# Passing Cyrillic characters as a URL parameter

Tags: iphone, urlencode, nsurlrequest

I need to pass Cyrillic characters as a parameter in a URL in my iPhone app.  A sample URL looks like:

http://www.mysite.com/script.php?message=страшная

When I use this URL in my browser, it returns the correct result.  However, in my app, the cyrillic is not liked, and I end up getting a "bad url" in the **didFailWithError** code.

I have tried several encodings in my browser to get around this, but with no luck.  Is there a way to actually send the exact URL example above via an iPhone app?  The snippet of code I am using is:

```
selectedWord = @"страшная";
NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/script.php?message=%@", selectedWord];
NSLog (requestURL);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

In the above code, I have hardcoded the cyrillic word in the **NSString *selectedWord** for debug purposes.  In the real application it will be dynamic based on user input.

I have tried a more complex **POST**, thinking that I could pass the cyrillic as data rather than text, but either I am doing it wrong, or it doesn't work either.

Any example regarding encoding I can try in my browser, then implement in the app would be helpful.  I realize that the cyrillic is being rejected in the **NSURL**, but I was hoping there was a way around it with different code or encoding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What if you change it to:

```
encodedSelectedWord = [selectedWord stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/script.php?message=%@", encodedSelectedWord];
```

[documentation link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:)

Comment: Thanks Robot K!  That worked!I guess I really need to search the documentation more for all the possible encodings.  I didn't see that one mentioned where I looked!

Comment: It's not easy to find. NSString is a huge class, and some of the methods names are rather confusing.

Comment: Thank you, it works also for spanish special characters like á, é, í, ó, ú and ñ.

Comment: NSString * encodedString = [@"string to encode" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]]; use this because your method is deprecated